# pointer from input to list item

Tags: html, css

I have a small section of code that has an unordered list in one div and an input in a div underneath, creating a somewhat 'tab-like' interface for the list items. This is what I want but I"m trying to figure out how to create a pointer from the top of the input that points to the corresponding list item.

If I click the public item, I would want an arrow pointing from the input to 'Public' and same for internal.

Something like this:

[image: pointer]

I've tried some border methods but nothing gets me close, as I want it to be created from the border of the input essentially.

How can I do this?

```css
 .tabs{
  margin-top: 30px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1rem;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tabs ul{
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  padding:0px !important;
}

.tabs li{
  display:block;
  text-align:center !important;
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-bottom:-.15em;
}

.tabs li.is-active a{
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 color:black;
}

.tabs a.is-active {
border-bottom:2px solid black;
}

.tabs a:hover{
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row notesInput">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="tabs">
      <ul style="border-bottom:none !important; text-decoration:none">
        <li>Public</li>
        <li>Internal</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="public">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I've tried :

```css
.tabs {
  margin-top: 30px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1rem;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tabs ul {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.tabs li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center !important;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: -.15em;
}

.tabs li.is-active a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
}

.tabs a.is-active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.tabs a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

input {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="row notesInput">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="tabs">
      <ul style="border-bottom:none !important; text-decoration:none">
        <li>Public</li>
        <li>Internal</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="public">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No JS? Pure CSS?

Comment: I'm open to JS, but I'm using Vue on this page so I figured it may be easier to use css. I'm honestly open to either way @IslamElshobokshy

Comment: There is no need for JS to accomplish this. Can we see what you've tried? This can be done with some CSS pseudo-element styles.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen the JS would've been for when we'd click on either `li`, not to create the triangle :-)

Comment: The only thing that got me anywhere close to what I want was ``` clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);```

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I misunderstood your comment, I apologise!

Comment: @TomN. Can we see that implemented in your example?

Comment: @chriskirknielsen it is there now

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo-element like `:before` for each `<li>`. So, you can apply border, background and rotate this pseudo-element using `transform: rotate()` to create the triangle form you want. Finally, you position it to be near the input.

Some changes were made on CSS, like applying border on input and `overflow and overflow-x` were removed.
`.active` class is being use to switch the li selected, changing the `content` property of the pseudo-element from `''` to `none`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tabs ul li').forEach(function(li) {
  li.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
      return;
    };
    document.querySelector('.tabs .active').classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
 .tabs{
  margin-top: 30px;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1rem;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tabs ul{
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  padding:0px !important;
}

.tabs li {
  display:block;
  text-align:center !important;
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-bottom:-.15em;
  position: relative;
}

.tabs li:before {
  content: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-left: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
  border-top: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
  bottom: -18px;
  left: calc(50% - 3px);
}

.tabs li.active:before {
  content: '';
}

.tabs li.is-active a{
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 color:black;
}

.tabs a.is-active {
border-bottom:2px solid black;
}

.tabs a:hover{
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.input input {
  border: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
}
```

```html
<div class="row notesInput">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="tabs">
      <ul style="border-bottom:none !important; text-decoration:none">
        <li class="active">Public</li>
        <li>Internal</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" name="public">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```